# Missing references in tortus SVN

Tags: svn, version-control, assembly-references

I am checking out code from an SVN server, and when I do, all of the references are some how not picking up in the code. The references are still there in the references folder, but they aren't being picked up by the rest of the code in the using sections. This is quite frustrating and It sucks because I cant get any work done because of it. Does anyone have any ideas. Should I talk to the person putting the code up on the server?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that either, you have the correct version of the referenced files, or set versionspecific to false on your references.

It would be nice if MS would display a "wrong Version" error instead of "Not Found".